# Separate aggregated row into distinct rows, adding a unique count in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset that has several rows and columns, however within the column labeled, 'active', I wish to remove the aggregation and separate this into its own unique count. I also wish to add a column that gives this count a unique id.

**Data**

```
Pair    gen     box    date     active

sox     black    bl     2021     3
sox     red      re     2021     2
```

**Desired**

```
Pair    gen     box    date     active    count

sox     black      bl     2021     1      b101
sox     black      bl     2021     1      bl02
sox     black      bl     2021     1      bl02
sox     red        re     2021     1      re01
sox     red        re     2021     1      re02
```

The 'active' column now has 3 and 2 distinct rows respectively, along with a distinct count ID (based on the 'box' column) instead of an aggregation.

**Doing**

A SO assisted with a similar dilemma, and I am taking this approach:

```
# Melt Table Into New Form
df = df.melt(col_level=0, value_name='count', var_name='bl')

# Repeat Based on Count
df = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df['count']))
# Set Count To 1
df['count'] = 1


# Add Suffix to Each ID
df['ID'] = df['ID'] + (
    (df.groupby('ID').cumcount() + 1)
        .astype(str)
        .str.zfill(2)
)
```

This works, however, I am not able to retain the other columns as well as set individual var names such as:

```
bl01
bl02

re01
re02
```

Any suggestion or advice is appreciated

Comment: good [mcve] btw!

Comment: Ah thank you! Let me look at this documentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `melt` for this problem and can `reindex` and `repeat` with the following. Keep in mind that for the `count` column, I realize that if each group has a size > `10` that it would show up as `bl010` as an example, when you really want `bl10`. The number formatting works with the provided sample data though with group size less than 10, and with group size > 10, it is not clear what the desired output is:

```
df = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df['active'])).assign(active=1)
df['count'] = df['box'] + '0' + (df.groupby(['Pair', 'gen', 'box']).cumcount() + 1).astype(str)
df
Out[1]: 
  Pair    gen box  date  active count
0  sox  black  bl  2021       1  bl01
0  sox  black  bl  2021       1  bl02
0  sox  black  bl  2021       1  bl03
1  sox    red  re  2021       1  re01
1  sox    red  re  2021       1  re02
```

Comment: let me try this above example, thank you for your assistance on this

Answer (score 1):

another method would be a concat along your axis, then use cumcount to create your count column.

```
dfs = pd.concat([pd.concat([y.assign(active=1,)] * act)
           for (idx,act),y in df.groupby([df.index, df['active']])])

dfs['count'] = dfs['box'] + (dfs.groupby('box').cumcount() + 1).astype(str).str.zfill(2)

print(dfs)

  Pair    gen box  date  active count
0  sox  black  bl  2021       1  bl01
0  sox  black  bl  2021       1  bl02
0  sox  black  bl  2021       1  bl03
1  sox    red  re  2021       1  re01
1  sox    red  re  2021       1  re02
```